# AWS Instance Connect with a resource tag condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, aws-ec2-instance-connect

I am trying to limit ssh access to ec2 instances by using a resource tag condition in my instance connect policy. So basically I have something like that:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2-instance-connect:SendSSHPublicKey",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*",,
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {"ec2:ResourceTag/Squad": "blah"}
        }
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
}
```

However, that seems it doesn't work. Isn't instance connect able to use the `ec2:ResourceTag` condition? I have seen it working with a condition like `ec2:osuser`, so I am wondering if there is a limitation or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @LeoGallucci unfortunately no. It seems that it's not supported.

Comment: weird but there is sample that suggests it does , but it doesn't
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html.

Reference for services which support tags: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_aws-services-that-work-with-iam.html

Answer (score 0):

I think IAM policy not able to limitation ssh access. I'm not sure but I haven't hear anyone IAM policy for limitation SSH. I think it's must be setup into your EC2 instance.